# (pattern, nlp) ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

Tags: python, numpy, design-patterns, nlp, python-pattern

I have been trying to install a Reddit scraper (Python w/ Pattern / NLP https://github.com/jaijuneja/reddit-nlp) but I keep having the problem of my Numpy being incompatible.

I've tried to uninstall and re-install Numpy, Pattern, Python... Any idea how to fix this?

This is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "example-TRP.py", line 1, in <module>
        from redditnlp import RedditWordCounter, TfidfCorpus
      File "/Users/-----/Desktop/reddit-nlp/redditnlp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        import nltk
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
        from nltk.collocations import *
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 39, in <module>
        from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        from nltk.metrics.scores import          (accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/scores.py", line 18, in <module>
        from scipy.stats.stats import betai
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 324, in <module>
        from .stats import *
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 242, in <module>
        import scipy.special as special
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 531, in <module>
        from ._ufuncs import *
      File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy/special/_ufuncs.c:19983)
    ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```